# JS/CSS: removing flexbox last row orphan items by using a resize event listener to show/hide elements?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a flex grid that show items of different widths (rectangle, square, etc) and it pulls data from an API so the list is dynamic so each row is always different. This often results in "orphan" flex items at the end of the flex grid, especially at lower breakpoints.

I've noticed I usually only get 2 or 3 items lingering in the last row.

My goal is to only show full rows and get rid of all orphan items.

[image]

I thought of different ways to accomplish this and I noticed that all my orphan items are both 1) occurring when I shrink my screen below `1750px` and 2) the orphan items are above 300px, large since they have no content next time to them that forces them to be small.

I thought I would add a `resize` event listener to check check only the last 6 items of my flex grid.  If it's height is above `310`, I add the style `display: none` , otherwise `display: block`.

```
this.throttledCheckOrphanItems = throttle(() => this.checkOrphanItems(), 300);
window.addEventListener('resize', this.throttledCheckOrphanItems);
```

```js
checkOrphanItems() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 1750) {
    return;
  }
  const items = document.getQuerySelectorAll('.movieItems');

  for (let x = items.length - 1; x >= items.length - 6; x--) {
    const height = items[x].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    if (height >= 310) {
      items[x].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      items[x].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
},
```

It "works" but it is not a smooth experience.

I know this isn't a great solution but I can't find another way without sacrificing the setup of my grid.  Is there a better way I can *only* show full rows?  If not, is there a way to optimize my solution or make it more performant?

Comment: A nice trick, if you can, is to always pull 60 items at a time. 60 is a magical number, because it has many dividers. With 60 items, you can have rows of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 items, and they will always be full, without orphan.

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks! unfortunately, I am always displaying 23 items

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same question...